# Gwt pie chart radius

Tags: gwt, charts

I am using gwt and Google Chart Tools.

wondering whether there is a way to set radius to pie chart?

Comment: Com'on I just need to know that. I already set like that:          options.setWidth(400);
options.setHeight(250); But it just resizes iframe size(which contains pie chart not chart radius). Pie chart stays the same

Comment: Hi, Did you ever find solution for this? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to set the `width` and `height`, it should increase the radius.

Check [this example](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) on how to use the options.